# $l$-adic cohomology under homotopy

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

To a smooth proper algebraic variety $V$ over a field $k$ and a prime $l$ we can associate representations of the Galois group $Gal(k^{sep}/k)$ on the $l$-adic cohomology groups $H^i_{\acute{e}t}(V_{k^{sep}}, \mathbb{Q}_l)$.

How do these Galois modules behave under ($\mathbb{A}^1$ or etale) homotopy? Are they invariants of homotopy type of $V$?

Comment: Yes for l prime to the characteristic.